# Error: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'validateStatus' in... occurring for both put and post resquest

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, axios

I'm working on a project where I am trying to have my cart saved to the database (mongodb) while it's in use. I'm getting an error stating

> Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'validateStatus' in 62d61b450a76374089e56b75 (id).

Originally, I was sending a put request, but even when I changed it to a post request after seeing examples advising that with this error you need to change it to a post request, I'm still getting the same error. Does anyone know why this is happening?

cartActions.js

```
export const addInPreOrderCart = (userCartId, productId, pre_orderQty) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  dispatch({ type: CART_ADD_PREORDER_REQUEST, payload: userCartId, productId, pre_orderQty });
  try {
      const { data } = await Axios.put(`${BASE_URL}/api/carts/pre_orderQty`, 
      userCartId, 
      productId, 
      pre_orderQty, {
      });
      dispatch({ type: CART_ADD_PREORDER_SUCCESS, payload: data });
  } catch (error) {
      dispatch({
          type: CART_ADD_PREORDER_FAIL,
          payload: error.response && error.response.data.message ? error.response.data.message : error.message,
      });
  }
};
```

cartReducers.js

```
export const cartAddPreOrderReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CART_ADD_PREORDER_REQUEST:
      return { ...state, loading: true };
    case CART_ADD_PREORDER_SUCCESS:
      return { ...state, loading: false, success: true, cart: action.payload };
    case CART_ADD_PREORDER_FAIL:
      return { ...state, loading: false, error: action.payload };
    case CART_ADD_PREORDER_RESET:
      return {};
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

cartRouter.js

```
cartRouter.put(
        '/pre_orderQty',
        expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
            console.log(req.body)
            const cart = await Cart.findOne({ userCartId: req.body.userCartId});
            if (cart.cartItems.find((x) => x.productId === req.body.productId)) {
                let carT = cart.cartItems
                for (var items of carT) {
                    if (items.productId  === req.body.productId) {
                        items.pre_orderQty = req.body.pre_orderQty;
                    }
                }
            const updatedCart = await cart.save();
            res.send({ message: 'Cart Item Updated', cart: updatedCart });
            } else {
                res.status(404).send({ message: 'Cart Not Found' });
            }
        }),
      );
```

Comment: What driver are you using to communicate to MongoDB from NodeJS? Also, your `find` operation finds the element you're looking for, but you throw it away and iterate over the entire collection instead. I'd just do `const item = cart.cartItems.find((x) => x.productId === req.body.productId); if (item) { item.pre_orderQty = req.body.pre_orderQty; }`. I don't know why you're getting the error though.

Comment: Hi @HereticMonkey, Oh okay, thank you! I'm using mongoose to connect to the mongo driver. ```mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL || 'mongodb://localhost/AM', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, });``` (This is from my server.js document)